# incuding file causes: "Cannot redeclare", not including: "Call to undefined function"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 3 files located in the same folder: *header.php*, *profile.php* and *domain-name.php*.

*domain-name.php:*

```
<?php
function returnDomainName(){
    return 'http://localhost/wordpress/';
}
?>
```

*header.php:*

```
...
<?php include 'domain-name.php';?>
...
<?php echo '<a href="' . returnDomainName() . 'login">Sign in</a>';?> // Here I'm just using returnDomainName function, and it works. Nothing special
...
<body <?php body_class();?>> // wordpress function, which in our case calls profile.php
```

*profile.php:*

```
include 'domain-name.php'; // If I'm including this one, page don't even load, with 'cannot redeclare' error

if(array_key_exists('logout', $_POST)) { // When I press logout button without including domain-name, I get an error 'call to undefined function'
    header('Location: ' . returnDomainName());
    wp_logout();
    exit();
}
```

When I'm trying to include donmain-name in profile, I'm getting an error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare returnDomainName()`.

But when I don't, I'm getting this `Call to undefined function returnDomainName()`

How can I get out of this error loop?

*WordPress 5.4.1, PHP 7.4.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `require_once` or `include_once` instead of `include`.